# Continuous distribution additivity contradiction?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If a random variable $X$ is continuous, then by definition, 
$$(1) \quad P(X=x) = 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\,.$$
Also, by additivity,
$$(2) \quad P(X \le c) = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{R} \le c} P(X = x)\,.$$
Doesn't $(1)$ imply that $(2)$ must equal $0$?

Comment: No, that is not the implication - you are taking an uncountable sum, and the [third axiom of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom) on additivity only deals with countable sums

Comment: That's where *integral* enters the picture. It's $$P(X<c) =P(X\le c) =\int_{-\infty}^c f(x)\, dx$$ where $f$ is the *density function* of $X$ (basically defined by this formula).

Comment: For example, consider $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(1).$ You have $E(X) = \int_0^\infty x\,e^{-x}\,dx = 1$ and $P(X <c) = \int_0^c e^{-x}\,dx = 1 - e^c,$ for $c > 0.$